# Android programming on text views

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

can anybody help me ? I want to embed this block of code in my program but I dont know where to place it and I think it is an error for working with textViews in android

```
 final TextView img1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
 final TextView img2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.img2);   
 btnV.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            img1.setText(btnV.getText());

        }
img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            img1.setText("");
        }

     });
```

Comment: if((img1 == null || img1 == "")){
switch(v.getId()){
case btnVisClicked:
img1.setText(btnV.getText());
btnV.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
break;
.
.
.
.
default:
break;
}

if((img2 == null || img2 == "")){

   //some code
switch(v.getId()){
case btnVisClicked:
img1.setText(btnV.getText());
btnV.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
break;
default:
break;
}`enter code here`

else{
}

Comment: You can write this code in onCreate method.

Comment: Please upload your code into question by editing the question.

Comment: You are missing a `}` before starting else..

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     final TextView img1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
      TextView img2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.img2);   
      final Button btnV = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1); 
     btnV.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                img1.setText(btnV.getText());

            }

     });

     img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                img1.setText("");
            }

         });


}


}
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="img1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/img2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="img2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="btn1" />
```

Comment: thanks .. but I am working with lots of textViews and buttons that if the first textview is null or contains nothing it will get the string of a button that I clicked, assume that the first textview contains string then I clicked another button it will be placed on the second textview

Comment: put null check and if any val is null the use any other val as required by your application.
if you can  post you code then i will be posting the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    use OnFocusChangeListener:

 img1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                        img2.setText("");

                    }
                });
```